# What is this leaking pipe?

Tags: sewer, leaking, spigot

I have this soldered looking pipe protruding from the foundation of my house that continues to leak water. What could this be possibly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The location almost makes me think it was the old path to get water outside.  Check inside that wall for a second pipe going outside.  It should have a shut off valve that is not closed completely or leaking.

Comment: Thank you @crip659. I’ll check

Comment: Old sprinkler supply line.

Comment: Looks like it's just crimped "closed" and may have just spring a leak.  Maybe the right thing to do is excavate some more so there's working room, cut off the crimp, clean it up, and solder a cap on.